# Convert Array to Json for save to database

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hello i have an array like this:

```
$data = Array(
[0] => {"detail":"l,red","sku":"#123","price":"50","stok":""}
[1] => {"detail":"l,black","sku":"#123","price":"50","stok":""}
[2] => {"detail":"m,red","sku":"#123","price":"50","stok":""}
[3] => {"detail":"m,black","sku":"#123","price":"50","stok":""}
[4] => {"detail":"s,red","sku":"#123","price":"50","stok":""}
[5] => {"detail":"s,black","sku":"#123","price":"50","stok":""}
)
```

when i use this :

```
$data = json_encode($data , JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

but the result like :

```
{"0":"{\"detail\":\"l,red\",\"sku\":\"#123\",\"price\":\"50\",\"stok\":\"\"}","1":"{\"detail\":\"l,black\",\"sku\":\"#123\",\"price\":\"50\",\"stok\":\"\"}","2":"{\"detail\":\"m,red\",\"sku\":\"#123\",\"price\":\"50\",\"stok\":\"\"}","3":"{\"detail\":\"m,black\",\"sku\":\"#123\",\"price\":\"50\",\"stok\":\"\"}","4":"{\"detail\":\"s,red\",\"sku\":\"#123\",\"price\":\"50\",\"stok\":\"\"}","5":"{\"detail\":\"s,black\",\"sku\":\"#123\",\"price\":\"50\",\"stok\":\"\"}"}
```

i don't like "\" result. is there something wrong?

Comment: Your code does not give that result.

Comment: How to do you get to that result? Because there is nothing wrong with `$data = json_decode($data , JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber because `json_decode` accepts a string and returns object or array. For converting an array to JSON is used `json_encode`

Comment: No, i just don't like before " they have \ symbol.

Comment: Well the code you've shown doesn't add the \ to the "

Comment: @AndyAjhisRamadhan that's OK. When you encodes JSON string second time, " must be escaped

Comment: oh sorry im going wrong, i have been to encode but result some like \"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't like these slashes, you should decode inner JSON strings first:

```
$data = json_encode(array_map(function ($item) {
    return json_decode($item, true);
}, $data), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: Begs the question how he came to make `$data` in the first place huh? :) But yes, this would fix his issue. But surely he could have made the original array of data correctly in the first place! LOL.

Comment: @IncredibleHat that's the question, yea :)

Comment: LOL. Thx a lot @Nikita Leshchev. :)